# Buying of a noble title

Tags: united-kingdom, name-title

I recently came across some sites that let you purchase a noble title like: Lord, Lady, Duke, Duchess, Marquis, Count,...

How can they sell such titles (they used to be given by the King/Queen of England)?
Are these titles legitimate? And how do they work?

[Elite-titles](https://elite-titles.myshopify.com/) and
[Scottishlands](https://www.scottishlands.com/benefits.php) are examples of sites selling titles.

Comment: Did you read the site(s)? It says "Disclaimer: These effective Titles are not to be mistaken for real Titles (bestowed by the State, etc) or used for any fraudulent means."

Comment: And in any case, buying nobility titles or high offices is a time honored tradition with lots of examples everywhere. But those need the agreement of either to provider of titles (for titles of new creation) or its holder (for people who married into nobility of account of their wealth) and the negotiation is way more subtle than posting a website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply, they aren't selling genuine titles. There are two limited exceptions:

Note that there is considerable difference between Scottish and English law in this area.

> You cannot purchase a genuine British title, with one exception, the
>   **feudal title of a Scottish baron**; and certainly cannot buy a peerage
>   title. Scottish Feudal Baronies fetch a mighty price; the Barony of
>   MacDonald was up for sale at over £1 million.

Richard, 7th Earl of Bradford, at http://www.faketitles.com/

For Scottish feudal baronies,

> For centuries baronies conferred important commercial benefits and
>   legal privileges, but they are now personal titles with no powers or
>   responsibilities. Holders are able to sell, gift or bequeath them, as
>   ‘incorporeal’ property separate from the ownership of land, and there
>   is a small but active market for them.

https://www.lindsays.co.uk/services/for-you-and-your-family/scottish-barony-titles

> We generally estimate legal fees between £2,000 -£3,000 for the
>   acquisition of a barony and £3,000 -£4,000 for an earldom.  **The barony
>   itself will cost in the region of £75,000 or more** in the case
>   ofalordship, earldomor marquisate.

https://www.lindsays.co.uk/assets/downloads/Buying-a-Scottish-Barony-Title.pdf

In England,

> it is possible you can purchase a Lordship of the Manor, **which does
>   not give you a title**, but enables  you to put after your name, Lord of
>   the Manor of Lower Piddling-in-the-Trough or some  such place.

Richard, 7th Earl of Bradford, at http://www.faketitles.com/

> **When I acquire a barony title what will my name be?**
>
> Let us assume that your name is John Smith and that you have acquired
>   the Barony of Strathglen. You can then style yourself John Smith,
>   Baron of Strathglen. But note, neither Baron Strathglen nor Baron
>   Smith of Strathglen because both of these would indicate a peerage
>   title and barony titles are feudal titles.

https://baronytitles.com/frequently-asked-questions/